# Reset dock icons while log off

Tags: dock, script

I have an iMac for public use, I want to ensure the dock icon won't be changed by others (i.e. keep factory setting).

Currently I know the following two commands can do this:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock
killall Dock
```

However, when I insert this two lines of code into an Logoff script, it won't work.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Reset the dock
defaults delete com.apple.dock
killall Dock

exit 0
```

The script is OK and other commands in that script are functioning too.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're logging out you can just delete the *com.apple.dock.plist* file in the script using the `rm` command and no need to use the `killall` and `defaults` commands.  I just tested this with a logout script and it reset the Dock to the default Dock when logging back in.

I used: `rm "/Users/$USER/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist"`